# Not able to set Admob Ads at bottom in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, webview, admob, android-constraintlayout

I just set my webview in ConstraintLayout. I am not able to show Banner at bottom of activity. It always overlays the action bar. All i want to show id first Action bar then webview then at bottom banner ads.
Below image show the current layout:

[image]

Here is my activity_browser.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".webBrowser.BrowserActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_browser_full" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ads"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is content_browser_full.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"/>



</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you already solve but some other will help this.

You need to add bellow code

```
ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

full code:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not see `ConstraintLayout` but only a `CoordinatorLayout` The easy way is to add this line:

```
 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

to your `AdView`. Bear in mind this will also be on top of your browser(`WebView`) but a the bottom of the Screen. If it fits your need use it, else elaborate what you want.

Comment: Yes, its my mistake. Its CoordinateLayout.

Comment: So did you try my solution?? @ShahbazAlam